# Netplan and NIC not working after changing DNS

Tags: networking, server

I'm running FreeNas 11.2U7 and had several VMs running Ubuntu server 18.4.3 LTS.

I created another server also with Ubuntu 18.4.3 LTS specifically for Pi-hole which is working perfectly. I changed my router to use that DNS from the pihole. My desktop, devices, and all the other VMs running Ubuntu are working as expected and are able to access the internet.

One of my VMs is not. I've tried to run `sudo netplan apply` and generally any netplan command and I get `sudo: netplan: command not found`.

When I enter `networkctl` I get:

```
ID LINK    TYPE       OPERATIONAL   SETUP
 1 lo      loopback   carrier       unmanaged
 2 enp0s4  ether      off           unmanaged
```

Strangely, when it type `whereis netplan` I get:

```
netplan: /etc/netplan/ /usr/share/netplan
```

So this is where my knowledge stops. Any ideas?

Comment: Before reinstalling netplan.io, I'd first run a `fsck` to assure that there's nothing more wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing the important binary /usr/sbin/netplan.

Reinstall the `netplan.io` package: `sudo apt install --reinstall netplan.io`

If the package is not in your local cache, you will need to download it from http://packages.ubuntu.com and sneakernet it across to the affected machine.

Comment: Looks like the Ubuntu repo is producing an error for me at the moment, I'll try back  later. I expect that once I have the package, I'll be able to add it to a local disk and access it via my VM. I'll report back.

Comment: This was a doozy. Here is what I did: I downloaded the file, created a new zvol in freenas mounted it to one of my live VMs. Then mounted that zvol to the broken VM. I then found that there were three dependencies, I then had to add those three files. Then I ran netplan apply and lo and behold I was able to ping google.com. Thank you, user535733